# Page speed performing poorly specifically on OS X versions of Chrome. What gives?

Tags: performance, page-speed, google-chrome, mac

I'm digging into page speed within my Google Analytics, and saw that I'm having higher than average load times with Chrome, which was unexpected. Digging in further by operating system, the issue seems to be primarily with Chrome on OS X 10.9.

[image: Page load times - high for Chrome on OS X]

Chrome on Mac OSX 10.11 and Windows 8.1 are also higher than average, but nothing compared to this one version of Chrome on OS X Intel 10.9, where the average page load time is nearly 10x higher than other browser / OS combinations. Several hundred monthly visitors are using this version, so I'd like to figure this out.

Any ideas on how I can diagnose this? Any known issues I should be aware of? Add a comment if you need any more info from me. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possibly dumb question but I'll ask anyway. How certain are you that these visits are legit and not some poorly written bot or scraper spoofing that user agent? I ask because both older and newer versions of the same browser/OS combo are way faster.

Comment: No, that's a good question, I did conflate pageviews with visitors earlier. Digging into my audience analytics and looking at browser / OS stats there, I see several hundred unique sessions for the Chrome / Intel 10.9 combo, with no significant difference in pages per session or time on site from other combos. On the one hand, this seems like real usage from that combo. On the other, if the page load time were this bad (23 seconds), there should be an impact on those stats. Could one slow-loading bot spoofing that combo cause this? Does GA not discard outliers when calculating averages?